# Contenteditable consistancy with enter key?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

Using a contenteditable div as a rich text editor; I've noticed that every browser handles the enter key differently. (FF inserts `<br>`, IE `<p>`, and chrome `<div>`)

Whats the best way to go about making the enter key consistent with all browsers? Preferably avoiding having each use `<p>` because I dislike the double space that causes between lines.

Comment: This topic is already discussed on SO and easy to Goog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814094/how-to-create-a-paragraph-on-enter-in-a-contenteditable-div?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950350/behaviour-of-enter-key-in-contenteditable-div?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974533/insert-newline-on-enter-key-in-contenteditable-div?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737463/contenteditable-paragraph-tag-on-enter?rq=1 and so on and so on...

Comment: I've been reading questions on it for the past 2 hours and havn't found anything that works yet...

Comment: OK, I'll reopen your question if you show what you tried so far, posting a code that reproduces your issue - and with an explanation where you're stuck at. Tip: posting a comment on an already existing answer should help to get more clarifications from the Answerer. If you think your question is specific than you really need to show some code.